# SHELL text to html

Tags: html, bash, shell, unix, text

now I have this shell code and I need to add HTML tags to simple text. In other words I need to format text to basic HTML code.

Now i have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# t2h {$1} html-ize a text file and save as foo.htm
NL="
"
cat $1 \
| sed -e 's/ at / at /g' \
| sed -e 's/[[:cntrl:]]/ /g'\
| sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*$//g' \
| sed -e '/^$/{'"$NL"'N'"$NL"'/^\n$/D'"$NL"'}' \
| sed -e 's/^$/<\/UL><P>/g' \
| sed -e '/<P>$/{'"$NL"'N'"$NL"'s/\n//'"$NL"'}'\
| sed -e 's/<P>[[:space:]]*"/<P><UL>"/' \
| sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*-/<BR> -/g' \
| sed -e 's/http:\/\/[[:graph:]\.\/]*/<A HREF="&">[&]<\/A> /g'\
                                > foo.htm
```

And here is an example of text:

```
"Greatest properly off ham exercise all. Unsatiable invitation its possession nor off. All difficulty estimating unreserved increasing the solicitude. Rapturous see performed tolerably departure end bed attention unfeeling. On unpleasing principles alteration of. Be at performed preferred determine collected. Him nay acuteness discourse listening estimable our law. Decisively it occasional advantages delightful in cultivated introduced. Like law mean form are sang loud lady put.     "

"Greatest properly off ham exercise all. Unsatiable invitation its possession nor off. All difficulty estimating unreserved increasing the solicitude. Rapturous see performed tolerably departure end bed attention unfeeling. On unpleasing principles alteration of. Be at performed preferred determine collected. Him nay acuteness discourse listening estimable our law. Decisively it occasional advantages delightful in cultivated introduced. Like law mean form are sang loud lady put.     "
```

And it needs to be something like this:

```
<html>
<p>Greatest properly off ham exercise all. Unsatiable invitation its possession nor off. All difficulty estimating unreserved increasing the solicitude. Rapturous see performed tolerably departure end bed attention unfeeling. On unpleasing principles alteration of. Be at performed preferred determine collected. Him nay acuteness discourse listening estimable our law. Decisively it occasional advantages delightful in cultivated introduced. Like law mean form are sang loud lady put.</p><br />
<br />
<p>Greatest properly off ham exercise all. Unsatiable invitation its possession nor off. All difficulty estimating unreserved increasing the solicitude. Rapturous see performed tolerably departure end bed attention unfeeling. On unpleasing principles alteration of. Be at performed preferred determine collected. Him nay acuteness discourse listening estimable our law. Decisively it occasional advantages delightful in cultivated introduced. Like law mean form are sang loud lady put.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use MarkDown?

Comment: Is your first "sed" command actually doing anything ?  BTW, you have the script, the input and the output but do you also have a question about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to use "sed" to replace newlines for whatever reason.
THIS WILL NOT WORK.
"sed" is blind for newlines because "sed" is working line oriented.
That means that the newline gets stripped by "sed" before it starts to evaluate.

The easiest workaround is using "tr" to replace every newline with another character before you start with "sed".
This other character is not supposed to be a character that can be found in the textfile   (or you must make up your own escape sequence one way or the other).

If you corrected these errors and it still doesn't work, please post your corrected code.
And  also post what you expect each sed command to do.

P.S. You might be better off with bash' native string handling.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like this bash script DataFile is your file with text to be formatted

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '<html>' >foo.htm
cat DataFile |tr -d '"'|grep -v "^$" |\
while read Line
do
cat <<eof
  <p>${Line}</p><br><br>
eof
done >>foo.htm
echo '</html>' >>foo.htm
```